# Passing variables with URL not working quite right using PHP and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to update a page every 5000 milliseconds. It works great but I have ran into one issue. When I try and get data that is in the URL using `$_GET` or `$_POST` it does not work. It instead returns a value of a `1`. Here is some example code.

In `main.php` I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function worker() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Request.php', 
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#Live_data').html(data);
        },
        complete: function() {      
            setTimeout(worker, 5000);
        }
    });
})();
```

and when this is called it fires off the `request.php`. In `request.php` I have some code to grab what was added in the URL by a previous page but it dose not work. It goes something like this:

```
$value = $_get['test'];
```

This is supposed to return the value in the URL parameter `test` but it does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: you need parse the result or specify the `dataType` example `dataType:'text'`

Comment: You're not sending any values in your AJAX request; you need to add a `data` property with the required values to send in the request.

Comment: your not sending any data here ?

Comment: $_GET , not $_get in `$_get['test'];`

Comment: First thing: You are using `POST` in your ajax request and `GET` in your `Request.php`. Second is that you are using `Request.php` and `request.php`. One is capital, the other isnt. Third thing i notice is that you are using `$_get` instead of `$_GET`. This variable is case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to send data with the ajax query,

In this code, you can add GET data by append a query string to url value, or send POST data by setting data property of the request,

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Request.php?query=string&is=here', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: {to: 'post', goes: 'here'},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#Live_data').html(data);
        },
        complete: function() {      
            setTimeout(worker, 5000);
        }
    });
```

see also https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-settings

Comment: I sure did! Thank you!
    Request.php?query=<?php echo $string?>

Answer (score 1):

I've commented it as well but I'll post it as answer:

1. Change `POST` to `GET` in your jQuery AJAX request.
2. Use `request.php` instead of `Request.php` or the other way around.
3. Use `$_GET` instead of `$_get`. This variable is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your not sending any data here. You can send the required data in Url or in Data Field.

```
url: 'Request.php?test=xyz',
```

or

```
data: data,
```